Manga about a guy who is reborn or reincarnated weak
I need help finding something I read a while ago… basically this guy has no talent and I can’t remember if he was reborn or got reincarnated but he is in a fantasy world and no cheat abilities or nothing he goes through many trials and gets stronger.
A scene I remember pretty keenly was him in a forest with warped perception or something. I believe he was training his senses like everything would be silent beside one which would then be amplified. After training there he gets an opportunity to train in a space with warped time. He is close friends with some real strong lady and they promise to meet in the future. The lady ended up taking over a martial arts sect or something similar but was considered a great evil. I remember they met in a dungeon, but he’s fighting a mimic of her or something.

It’s called Worthless Reincarnation/Regression by the same author of Damn Reincarnation. I found a nice synopsis on Reddit

“In his first life, he wasn't blessed with much talent, and he carried
that lack of talent into his second life, which left his self-esteem a
bit on the lower side. Even though outsiders view him as this super
impressive genius for his age, he only focuses on getting better and
better because he knows that what would be natural for most takes more
time for him to master.
So, the story's this cool blend where his training mixes with
character growth and moving the plot along. And the outcome usually
has him winning quite a bunch of battles, though he does have a few
important losses sprinkled in.”

